# cannot add features to WFS layer

Tags: openlayers-3

I try to load some features from Geoserver to a vector layer in Openlayers 3.9.0.

```
var url =  'http://localhost:5550/geoserver/mymap/wfs?service=WFS&'+'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mymap:layer&'+'outputFormat=application/json&maxFeatures=50';         
var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857');
var extent = [2297128.5, 4618333, 2459120.25, 4763120];

var amir = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax(url, {type: 'GET'})
            .done(loadFeatures)
            .fail(function () {alert("error");});
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});

function loadFeatures(response) {
    formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
    var features = formatWFS.readFeatures(response);    
    amir.addFeatures(features);

//-----------OR---------------------    
    var features = amir.readFeatures(response);
    amir.addFeatures(features);
}

var fill = new ol.style.Fill({
color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
});

var stroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
});

var circle = new ol.style.Circle({
radius: 6,
fill: fill,
stroke: stroke
});

jake = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: amir,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: fill,
        stroke: stroke,
        image: circle
      })
});
```

In `loadFeatures` function if I use

```
formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
var features = formatWFS.readFeatures(response);    
amir.addFeatures(features);
```

I get `Uncaught AssertionError: Failure: Unknown source type` pointing to a openlayers line that throws errors and to this line of my code`var features = formatWFS.readFeatures(response);`.

If I use

```
var features = amir.readFeatures(response);
amir.addFeatures(features);
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: sourceVector.readFeatures is not a function` pointing to `var features = amir.readFeatures(response);` .

The request to the WFS looks ok, with `OK 200 status`. If I grab the request's URL sended to Geoserver and open it in a new tab I get raw GeoJSON like `{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":422,"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"layer.709","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[2391735.8907621,4695330.8039257005]},"geometry_name":"l_geom","properties":{"l_name":"Leeron"}},....//next feature`

So its a `FeatureCollection` not just an array. Not that I know how to handle this

I dont get why to set a `ol.format.WFS` and not just read/add features. I dont know how to debug and add the features to my layer

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2):

You are instructing GeoServer to use GeoJSON as output format, so you'll need to use the GeoJSON format in OpenLayers to parse the features. You should be able to simplify your source configuration to something like

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:5550/geoserver/mymap/wfs?service=WFS&' +
    'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mymap:layer&' +
    'outputFormat=application/json&maxFeatures=50';         
var amir = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  url: function(extent, projection) {
    return url + '&bbox=' + extent.join(',') +
        '&srsName=' + projection.getCode();
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});
```